# Numbers in different directions

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What's the two word phrase I'm looking for?**

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
    S I B F T A N
    R T C N P L Y
    H P B A T M Z
    A O H X O I W 
    K B G C A Y I
    E R U D S W B
    Q D A G M T O
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two word phrase you are looking for is

> **ROTATING HAND**

The grid can be compared to

> ... a clock, and the lines can be compared to a certain hand on it. We place the red dot of each line on 'X' in the middle and rotate the line according to the given angles. Then reading the letters in blue coloured spots, we get the answer.

> [image]

Comment: Well done :) Tick is yours!